# get list of supported countries from Faker

Tags: python, faker

Below is a sample script which helps me generate a lat lng within a specified country.

How do I get a list of supported locales from Faker that I could pass as the country_code property?

```
## https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html#localization 
## !pip install Faker
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
fake.local_latlng(country_code='GB', coords_only=False)
>('50.82882', '-0.32247', 'Lancing', 'GB', 'Europe/London')
```

Comment: Have you tried the link in the code that you posted?

Comment: yes, of course, but i can't find which method returns the list of countries supported, that i'd be able to loop through. Maybe i'm being thick, or perhaps short sighted.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you wanted a list of providers (which is on the page), not a #Python# list of providers...

Comment: https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/config.py you'll want to access the `AVAILABLE_LOCALES` variable in this file

Comment: Yeah, i know that you can put Faker(['en_US']) to add supported locales. But actually i just need a list of country codes that local_latlng supports.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/joke2k/faker/tree/master/faker/providers/geo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user1558604

```
from faker.config import AVAILABLE_LOCALES
def getLocale (lc):
  loc = lc.split('_')
  if len(loc)>1:
    return  loc[1].upper()
  else:
    return loc[0].upper()

[fake.local_latlng(country_code=getLocale(local), coords_only=False) for local in AVAILABLE_LOCALES]
```

Needs a little tidying up for some of the codes, but i think does it.

```
[('53.43333', '-7.95', 'Athlone', 'IE', 'Europe/Dublin'),
None,
('42.7', '27.25', 'Aytos', 'BG', 'Europe/Sofia'),
('45.44868', '-73.81669', 'Pointe-Claire', 'CA', 'America/Toronto'),
('59.37722', '28.19028', 'Narva', 'EE', 'Europe/Tallinn'),
('37.73222', '115.70111', 'Hengshui', 'CN', 'Asia/Shanghai'),
('51.39323', '0.47713', 'Strood', 'GB', 'Europe/London'),
('31.20176', '29.91582', 'Alexandria', 'EG', 'Africa/Cairo'),
('47.05', '15.46667', 'Sankt Peter', 'AT', 'Europe/Vienna'),
None,
None,
....
```

Comment: How might I extract all Faker's locale codes into a list of string?

Comment: `[local for local in AVAILABLE_LOCALES] ` perhaps.